# Problem with component bound to an api with axios in React Native not rendering

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm for the first time trying to consume an api with axios in react native.

My goal is to demonstrate the name of the state on the screen, from this api (https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/), however, when I map it with only a {date.name}, but the content is not displayed.

What would I be doing wrong?

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import { View, TextInput, ScrollView, FlatList, Text } from "react-native";
import { Container, SearchInput, SearchInputText } from "./styles";
import Header from "../../components/Header";
import DashedCircle from "../../components/DashedCircle";

import axios from "axios";

export default (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados/"
      );

      setData(response.data);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <>
      <DashedCircle />
      <Container>
        <Header onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()} />

        <SearchInput>
          <SearchInputText placeholder="Buscar estado" />
          <Icon
            name="search-outline"
            type="ionicon"
            color="#c4c4c4"
            style={{
              paddingHorizontal: 15,
              paddingVertical: 15,
            }}
          />
        </SearchInput>

        {data.map((item) => {
          <Text>{data.nome}</Text>;
        })}
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
```

[app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzSgu.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You are doing one mistake  , which using  {} , we have to return  and also instead of data we are using item to access the data like this :

```
{data.map((item) => {
      return(
      <Text>{item.nome}</Text>
       );
    })}
```

But if you don't want to use return use  :

```
 {data.map((item) => (
          <Text>{item.nome}</Text>;
        ))}
```

Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping `data` so call the name from `item`, try:

```js
{data.map((item) => {
    <Text>{item.nome}</Text>
})}
```